# Extracting array data from javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get the data in an array in javascript.

here's my arrayProgram in javascript:

```
    [0] => Array (
    [Program] => Array (
        [event_name] => Event Daily
        [keyword] => KVIP SHOWTIME
        [start_date] => 2017-04-07 12:00:00
        [end_date] => 2017-04-03 15:00:00
        [location] => Studio 1
        [slots] => 10
        [event_color] => #9a9aff
        [is_allday] => 1
        [repeat_program] => daily-weekly
        [repeat_every] => 1
        [repeat_days] => ,1,2,3,4,5,6
        [repeat_yearly] => 0
        [is_end] => 0
        )
    )
[1] => Array (
    [Program] => Array (
        [event_name] => NEWS
        [keyword] => KVIP NEWS
        [start_date] => 2017-04-30 05:30:00
        [end_date] => 2017-04-01 19:00:00
        [location] => Studio 4
        [slots] => 05
        [event_color] => #fb8979
        [is_allday] => 1
        [repeat_program] => monthly
        [repeat_every] => 0
        [repeat_days] => 
        )
    )
[2] => Array (
    [Program] => Array (
        [event_name] => ASAP
        [keyword] => KVIP ASAP
        [start_date] => 2017-12-31 12:00:00
        [end_date] => 2017-04-01 15:00:00
        [location] => Studio 10
        [slots] => 16
        [event_color] => #9a9aff
        [is_allday] => 1
        [repeat_program] => yearly
        [repeat_every] => 0
        [repeat_days] => 
        )
    )
```

how can I extract the data using a for loop? I tried using $.each but it doesn't work for me. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop by using `for` statement:

```
var arr = [/* your array data here*/];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    console.log( arr[i]['Program']['event_name'] );
    console.log( arr[i]['Program']['keyword'] );
    // ... use arr[i]['Program'][...] to access other attribute
}
```